# modal take margin from top on tablet screen but not on desktop screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter-3, user-experience

> desktop view :

[image: desktop]

> tablet view :

[image: tablet]

modal is rendring `after` the navigation header in `desktop view` but in `tablet view` there is showing `gap` between `navigation header` and `modal`.
how to remove that gap and make layout structure same as desktop view?

```
div#modal.modal {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scaleX(1);
 margin-top: 0vh;
 margin-right: 1px;
 width:40%;
 z-index:1;
 height:100% !important;

}
```

Comment: Please take screenshot and put here for describe better

Comment: where is html or phtml for this screen add that so we can proper understand why this issue being generating.

Comment: @neha katheriya could you share with us a **[minimal, repodrucible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned code of this image the question seems unclear.

*alternate solution:*

use `media query` and make `margin-top` *negative value* .

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    div#modal.modal{
        margin-top: -[value]
       }
    }
```